# Is it customary for sellers to pay the commission in brokered transactions?

Tags: principal-agent, transaction-costs

This question focuses on brokered transactions where 1) the intermediaries act as brokers (agents), not dealers, and 2) where both sides have an agent.

In the U.S., in buying/selling houses, it is customary for the seller to bear the commission cost.

The question is: is this general pattern (seller pays more of the brokerage fee) true in other brokered transactions? For instance, in brokered M&A deals?

Comment: Are you asking about the *incidence* of the cost? If the fee is say $5000, then aren't you really paying $5000 more for the house, than you would need to if there was no fee?